# How to pass third parameter to bind action call - react

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

In my application I have list of text boxes.For reflecting changes in text boxes I am calling handleChange function call. when I send third parameter(index) to function, e value becomes undefined.

**Html:**

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <Input type="select" placeholder="select"
     wrapperClassName="col-xs-12" value={this.props.lang}
     onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'language', index)}>
         <option value="en">en</option>
         <option value="de">de</option>
     </Input>
</div>
```

**Call:**

```
  handleChange(name, e) {
    this.state.description[0][name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({description: this.state.description});
    console.log('---updated--', this.state);
  }
```

How to send another parameter to handleChange function call on onChange event? How can I send multiple parameters?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never change `state` directly as you did on the first line of your `handleChange` method.

The `onChange` callback is not intended to be called with additional parameter, it's a callback, so just pass a function, not a function call. You're `'language'` and `index` parameters should be accessible from elsewhere within your component scope.

Comment: I am new to react. Recently I am developing webapp using react. I followed some example. Here I am updating state when form data is changing. Is it not a good approach?

Comment: You tagged your question with reactjs-flux, do you use Flux architecture in your app with Store ?

Comment: yeah actually it is react+flux+alt

Comment: So you should retrieve the state of your object from the Store. Take a look to [this article explaining Flux artchitecture](http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/)

Comment: Thanks.I am using flux+alt